# Is there a Range< ? extends Comparable> API in JDK

Tags: java, api, java-8

I am looking for a Range API in JDK8 which also exports some static utilities , but no luck uptill now. I am working on a interval scheduling algorithm which needs one.If not I will work to create a custom interface .

Comment: If it's not in [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html) then it's not there.

Comment: It's not a perfect dupe. The question "is there one in the JDK" can be answered with a single word: 'No'. However, that questions lists most of the library solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure, perhaps Google Guava has what you need:

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained

or perhaps Google can help ;)